# Pandas read_json() doesn't cast column dtypes

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm reading a json file with Pandas read_json(). If I just read it:

input:

```
df_grades = pd.read_json("students_grades.json")
df_grades.dtypes
```

output:

```
names                          object
gender                         object
race/ethnicity                 object
parental level of education    object
lunch                          object
test preparation course        object
math score                     object
reading score                  object
writing score                  object
dtype: object
```

It just reads every column of the json file as an object. Specifically, columns "math score", "reading score" and "writing score" need to be ints for my purpose. For some reason, using the "dtype" attribute of "read_json" doesn't work.

input:

```
df_grades = pd.read_json("students_grades.json", dtype={'math score': 'int64',
                                                        'reading score': 'int64',
                                                        'writng score': 'int64'})
df_grades.dtypes
```

output:

```
names                          object
gender                         object
race/ethnicity                 object
parental level of education    object
lunch                          object
test preparation course        object
math score                     object
reading score                  object
writing score                  object
dtype: object
```

Dtypes stay the same for some reason. What can be the reason?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it's not converting then you have some data issues that can't be converted to the required data type. this also explains why you get an error when trying to convert using `astype` after reading

Comment: Hello Asish. I think this is the problem. I'm gonna have to look at the data or ask for new one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can that documentation be an answer?

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.dtypes

col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object

df.astype('int32').dtypes

col1    int32
col2    int32
dtype: object
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: The problem is that that changes the dtype of every column. I just need to change for "math score",  "reading score" and "writing score".

I've tried with:

```
df_grades["math score"].astype('int32')
```

and get an enourmous error with ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' at the end.

Another way is df_grades.astype({'math score': 'int64'}), but I get the same error.